# Problems using Sequelize.where

Tags: sequelize.js

I can using `=` or `!=` instead of `'[Op.iLike]'`, but i need to use operator `like`(

`` Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col('projectRoles.name'), '[Op.iLike]', `%${ctx.request.query.filterString}%`), ``

How i can write this?

The documentation says that equality is used by default, I need to use the like operator, or iLike from Postgress db
[https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-where](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#static-method-where)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('LOWER', sequelize.col('projectRoles.name')), 'LIKE', `%${ctx.request.query.filterString.toLowerCase()}%`)
```